# Copy short integer in char array with 0s

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char, short

I'm having difficulty finding out a specific way to copy a short integer into a char array.

Let's say I have:

```
unsigned short xVal = 5;
unsigned short yVal = 12;
char x[3];
char y[3];
```

and I want to copy the short integers into the respective char arrays filling the empty digits with 0s:

```
char value output
x    5     0005
y    12    0012
```

How can it be done in c++?

Comment: Those are not `char` arrays. C or C++? Pick one...

Comment: I meant char arrays without the pointers '*'. Sorry about the mistake.

Comment: What you want is getting/printing the short's decimal string representation. If you write "copy", that means you want to copy the short's bytes into the array. You should edit the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be.

```
unsigned short xVal = 5;
unsigned short yVal = 12;
char x[5];
char y[5];
sprintf(x,"%04u",xVal);
sprintf(y,"%04u",yVal);
printf("%s\n",x);
printf("%s\n",y);
```

Note that x and y should be declared as char arrays of 5 elements for the null character

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you are using `char*` arrays. For `char` arrays you can use `memcpy`

```
unsigned short xVal = 5;
char x[3];
memset(x,0,sizeof(x));
memcpy(x,&xVal ,sizeof(xVal));
```

You might want to make sure that the sizeof `unsigned short` is actually 2 bytes first. It most likely is but it is a good idea to check. The output as `char` is not necessarily going to be what you expect it to be. It will depend on the endianness of your system for one thing. The above code will simply store the bit pattern of your values in the `char` array.

If you are certain that your unsigned short values are small enough to store in a `char` variable then you could try casting them to `char` instead. If they are larger than 128 though this is not possible.

If you want a generic conversion of these numbers to a string in C++, then you could use `ostringstream`

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

unsigned short num = 56; 
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << num;
std::string str_number = ss.str();   // str_number now = "56"
```

This has the added advantage of the `std::string` automatically sizing itself according to the number of digits in your `unsigned short`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use a stream to format the values, of course:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
struct formatter: virtual std::streambuf, std::ostream {
    template <int Size>
    formatter(char (&buffer)[Size])
        : std::ostream(this) {
        std::fill(buffer, buffer + Size, 0);
        this->setp(buffer, buffer + Size);
        this->width(4);
        this->fill('0');
    }
};

// ... 
char x[5];
char y[5];
formatter(x) << xVal << std::ends;
formatter(y) << yVal << std::ends;
```

The original type of the arrays, `char*[3]`, i.e., an array of three pointers to `char`, isn't too useful to create formatted values.

Answer (score 0):

I modified example of @mathematician1975 the following way. I think it is more correct. The code requires to include headers `<limits>`, `<cstdio>`and `<iostream>`

```
const int N = std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::digits10 + 1;
char s[N + sizeof( '\0' )];
unsigned short yVal = 12;

std::sprintf( s, "%0*hu", N, yVal );
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

For amateurs of standard algorithms I can suggest the following code

```
const int N = std::numeric_limits<unsigned short>::digits10 + 1;
char s[N + sizeof( '\0' )] = {};
int x = 12;

std::generate( std::reverse_iterator<char *>( s + N ), 
               std::reverse_iterator<char *>( s ),
               [=] () mutable -> char 
               {
                   char c =  x % 10 + '0';
                   x /= 10;
                   return ( c );
               } );

std::cout << s << std::endl;
```